# Spring + Hibernate + Tuckey Urlrewrite = LazyInitializationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

### Domain Description

I am using a combination of
**Spring** + **Hibernate** + **Tuckey Urlrewrite**
In a **Spring Framework** Web app.

I have a simple data strucutre
Special has 1:Many Image object

I am using the language in the url:
`http://site.com/`**en**`/someview` or
`http://site.com/`**de**`/someview` and so on
There is also a default url:
`http://site.com/`

I am using **Tucky Urlrewrite** to rewrite the urls from
`http://site.com/`**en**`/someview` to
`http://site.com/someview?lang=en`
in order select the correct language for the page
(*I am doing this to allow the user to simply change the language in the url and have the site change language accordingly*)

I am loading the Special object in the Default controller
I am passing the Special object to the view and loading the Images there.

### Problem Description

When hitting `http://site.com/` everything works as expected. Looking at the logs for Turkey it is **NOT** doing any rewrite.

When hitting `http://site.com/en/` or `http://site.com/de/` i am getting the dreaded
"*failed to lazily initialize a collection of role*"

I can prove that there is something with Tuckey Urlrewrite because when i enter the "rewritten" urls into the address bar they work and even removing Tuckey Urlrewrite all together.

### I have tried the following

- Loading the Images in the controller - did not work
- Using the OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor -- did not work
- Using Tuckey's dispatcher REQUEST/FORWARD -- did not work
- Using Tuckey's type="redirect" -- did work but as expected redirected the browser
- Used the OneToMany attribute's fetch=FetchType.EAGER -- worked (but in the long term not desirable)

I am open to all suggestions to remove the use of the FetchType.EAGER.

Some ideas i have are
- Different method of Url rewriting i.e. if it is possiable to set tomcat to handle the rewrite before the DispachFilter 
- Different urlrewriter i.e. different product, or internal Spring URL Rewriter

### Sites i have read

- [Why Doesn't Tuckey UrlRewrite Filter call chain.doFilter after a rule is matched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043593/why-doesnt-tuckey-urlrewrite-filter-call-chain-dofilter-after-a-rule-is-matched)
- [Hibernate lazy initialization exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665798/hibernate-lazy-initlaization-exception) (most promissing but nothing there worked)
- [Hibernate (JPA) how to do an eager query, loading all child objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70992/hibernate-jpa-how-to-do-an-eager-query-loading-all-child-objects) (finally to give up and use EAGER)

Really would be very thankful for any hints

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `OpenSessionInViewFilter`/`OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`, make sure that one of the following is true:

- `<filter-mapping>` of `Open...InViewFilter` is declared before `<filter-mapping>` of the Tuckey filter
- `<filter-mapping>` of `Open...InViewFilter` contains `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>`.

Otherwise your `Open...InViewFilter` won't be invoked, because Tuckey filter performs a forward when rewriting a URL, therefore filters declared after it should have `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` in order to be invoked.